# Using C# FormWindowState to restore up?

Tags: c#, restore, minimize, maximize, windowstate

I'd like to detect if my application is minimized under certain situations, and if it is, the window needs to be restored.  I can do that easily as follows:

```
if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

However, what happens if the user first maximizes the form, then minimizes it?  I don't know whether to set the `WindowState` to `FormWindowState.Normal` or `FormWindowState.Maximized`.  Is there a method or API call I can check to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown below does what you need.  Overriding the user's choice is pretty unwise btw.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        mLastState = this.WindowState;
    }
    FormWindowState mLastState;
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnResize(e);
        if (mLastState != this.WindowState) {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) this.WindowState = mLastState;
            else mLastState = this.WindowState;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question (or I didn't provide enough information).  I'm not overriding the user's choice.  This is a single-instance application with file associations.  When the user opens a file, I want the existing instance to come to the front.  Your code still solves my problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution to restore forms in MDI form. First you have to define:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
```

and when it comes to restore:

```
ShowWindowAsync(this.MdiChildren[i].Handle, this.SW_RESTORE);
```

This will restore form to the previous state without using additional state holders.
Also you may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/oneprocessonly.aspx) article interesting

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to call `this.Show()` and it will restore to the previous (visible) state.

Comment: Calling `this.Show()` does not cause the window to be restored.  Would be nice, though

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that utilizes the [OnResize method](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=WinForms) of the form

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837421/578731:

> Not sure this will work for everybody, but I ran into this today and [someone](http://twitter.com/#!/benjaminpalmer) on the team suggested "*have you tried **Normal***"?
>
> Turns out he was right. The following seems to nicely restore your window:
>
> ```
> if (myWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
>     myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
> ```
>
> That works just fine, restoring the window to Maximized if needed. It seems critical to check for the minimized state first as calling *WindowState.Normal* a second time will "restore" your window to its non-maximized state.
>
> Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't seem to work when I tested it..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best option (Microsoft said):

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
```