# How to restore a minimized Window in code-behind?

Tags: wpf, window, state, restore, minimize

This is somewhat of a mundane question but it seems to me there is no in-built method for it in WPF. There only seems to be the `WindowState` property which being an enum does not help since i cannot tell whether the Window was in the `Normal` or `Maximized` state before being minimized.

When clicking the taskbar icon the window is being restored just as expected, assuming its prior state, but i cannot seem to find any defined method which does that.

So i have been wondering if i am just missing something or if i need to use some custom interaction logic.

(*I'll post my current solution as answer*)

Comment: are you calling this.Show() ? or you are changing the state?

Comment: @Akash Kava `Window.Show` only affects the visibility, it has no effect on the window's state. Minimization is a state-issue.

Comment: Well I checked reflector calling Show() does call ShowWindow api as mentioned by others, I wanted to know whether have you tried this.Show() ? because I have used it and may be I have not noticed.

Comment: It does not call `ShowWindow` and it does not work. As i said, it only sets the visibility (and waits for the loaded event to fire).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Not sure this will work for everybody, but I ran into this today and [someone](http://twitter.com/#!/benjaminpalmer) on the team suggested "*have you tried **Normal***"?

Turns out he was right. The following seems to nicely restore your window:

```
if (myWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

That works just fine, restoring the window to Maximized if needed. It seems critical to check for the minimized state first as calling *WindowState.Normal* a second time will "restore" your window to its non-maximized state.

Comment: Similar sentiments to H.B. Spent ten minutes wondering how to pull this off before stumbling here and seeing it was just automatic.

Answer (score 28):

**SystemCommands** class has a static method called **RestoreWindow** that restores the window to previous state.

```
SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this); // this being the current window
```

[Note : **SystemCommands** class is part of .NET 4.5+ [(MSDN Ref)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcommands.restorewindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for projects that target to earlier versions of Framework can use the WPF Shell extension [(MSDN Ref)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.systemcommands.restorewindow.aspx)]

Comment: +1 When use `ShowInTaskbar="False"` with `TrayIcon` and changing `Visibility to Hidden`, then is problem with restore window back to Normal. But this works great.

Answer (score 16):

WPF's point of view is that this is an OS feature.  If you want to mess around with OS features you might have to get your hands dirty.  Luckily they have provided us with the tools to do so.  Here is a UN-minimize method that takes a WPF window and uses WIN32 to accomplish the effect without recording any state:

```
public static class Win32
{
    public static void Unminimize(Window window)
    {
        var hwnd = (HwndSource.FromVisual(window) as HwndSource).Handle;
        ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWindowCommands.Restore);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);

    private enum ShowWindowCommands : int
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or 
        /// maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. 
        /// An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
        /// </summary>
        Restore = 9,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I almost never useed external calls so far so i am wondering though, is there a way to import the full `ShowWindowCommands` enum?

Comment: @H.B.  The site pinvoke.net has the full enum; I scraped just the one line we needed.  You can google "pinvoke _win32api_" e.g. "pinvoke ShowWindow" to find code to cut and paste.  The rest of ShowWindowCommands is at http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/ShowWindowCommand.html

Comment: Thank you again (i was not aware that a partial definition of the enum would be sufficient)

Comment: Because it is interop only the size matters; even an int or uint would be OK.

Comment: A new answer came in, sorry to take the accept from you but simplicity is obviously preferable.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason,

```
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

didn't work for me.
So I used following code & it worked..

```
 Show();
 WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how i get it to restore right now: I handle the `StateChanged` event to keep track of the last state that was not `Minimized`

```
WindowState _lastNonMinimizedState = WindowState.Maximized;
private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState != System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        _lastNonMinimizedState = WindowState;
    }
}
```

To restore i then have to set that `WindowState` respectively:

```
this.WindowState = _lastNonMinimizedState;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, the accepted answer did not work for me. The "maximized" window, when recalled from the task bar would end up centering itself (displaying in its Normal size, even though its state is Maximized) on the screen and things like dragging the window by its title bar ended up not working. Eventually (pretty much by trial-and-error), I figured out how to do it. Thanks to @H.B. and @Eric Liprandi for guiding me to the answer! Code follows:

```
private bool windowIsMinimized = false;
private WindowState lastNonMinimizedState = WindowState.Normal;

private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.windowIsMinimized)
    {
        this.windowIsMinimized = false;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        this.WindowState = this.lastNonMinimizedState;
    }
    else if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.windowIsMinimized = true;
    }
}

private void Window_MinimizeButtonClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.lastNonMinimizedState = this.WindowState;
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    this.windowIsMinimized = true;
}

private void Window_MaximizeRestoreButtonClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }

    this.lastNonMinimizedState = this.WindowState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In native Windows you can restore your window to a previous state with `ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE)`:

> Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.

There's surely .Net counterpart to that.