# Is there a way i can draw a transparent WPF application over the desktop at all times?

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay, desktop, user32

Is there a way to make an WPF application persist on top of the desktop when one uses the show desktop shortcut (`WINDOWS+D`) on windows?

I am trying to make an desktop overlay application with widgets. `(Same concept as rainmeter)` I currently am using functions in `user32.dll` to keep the window positioned on top of the desktop.

This works perfectly fine until i use `WINDOWS+D`

I've tried:

- On the window Deactivated event, inserting the window's position above the Desktops position
- Parenting the window to the desktop

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is CTRL+D supposed to do, and what is it doing in your particular case?

Comment: @theMayer Show desktop, Edited it

Comment: I believe you mean "WINDOWS + D" and not CTRL.

Comment: @theMayer oh god, yes you're right my bad!

Answer (score 3):

One (possibly dirty) way would be to register a hotkey to capture a WIN+D call as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/824395/12167858

Once you have a way to capture the hotkey you can find out whether or not its trigger-event fires before or after the native WIN+D response (showing the desktop).

I did not test this myself just yet, however, if it does fire **after** the native response, you're good to go. Otherwise, if such a solution would be acceptable, you could use a Task.Delay() to wait for Windows to finish minimizing all visible windows.

/edit: I forgot the critical part: Once you have ensured that Windows is done doing its things, call the code below (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837421/12167858) to get the window back to its original state:

```
if (myWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying I have managed to get global hotkey capturing working for windows+d. When i execute the code you have provided nothing happens. The window state was and stays `WindowState.Normal` before and after the execution of the windows + d shortcut. It seems that the Z-Index of the desktop gets increased to hide all other windows.